# GRIB2 analysis time?

Tags: grib, grib-2

I am trying to understand the timestamps in a grib2 file containing hourly data.

From http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/csv.html:

`Time0 is the reference time, that is usually the analysis or start of the forecast time. Time1 is the verification time. For analyses, Time0 and Time1 will be the same.`

Does this mean that if my Time0 and Time1 are the same, say 1200Z, does that mean the data is for 1100-1200Z or 1200-1300Z?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that if my Time0 and Time1 are the same, say 1200Z,
>   does that mean the data is for 1100-1200Z or 1200-1300Z?

No, the data is valid at 12Z 00 minutes 00 seconds.  If the 
data were the average from 11Z to 12Z, then Time0 would be 11Z
and Time1 would be 12Z.  Of course there would be more metadata
saying whether the value is the average, max, or min value in that
one hour interval.

Comment: In this case I know the value is the accumulation, i.e. the sum. So it seems that the data is being distributed with either an incorrect start/end time.

Answer (score -1):

If Time0 = Time1, then you have an analysis that is valid for a specific time.  BTW the web page was updated.